# How can a div be positioned where it doesn't move off the page but changes positioning when you resize the browser?

Tags: css

I would like the div to move to the left or right when the browser is resized. However, the div should stop moving when it reaches the left edge of the browser.

For example: [apple.com](http://apple.com) [facebook.com](http://facebook.com)

This is what I have right now:

```
#someElement{
    background-image: url(images/someImg.png);
    width:200px;
    height:45px;
    position:absolute;
    right:68%;
    top:3px;
}
```

This changes the position of the div when the browser is resized but does not stop when it gets to the left edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the min-width in the body tag:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-width:100%;
    width: auto !important;
    width:100%;
}
```

This will stop the element from exiting to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of using `right:` why don't you use `left:`?

```
left: 25%;
```

Comment: I thought about that; however, I wanted the element to go to the left edge of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the parent of the element relative positioned. It will make the inner element positioned absolute relative to its parent.

```
#someElementWrapper{
  position: relative;
}

#someElement{
  background-image: url(images/someImg.png);
  width:200px;
  height:45px;
  position:absolute;
}
```